# OpenCV displays white image grab from webcam

Tags: python, opencv

I am going through the basic OpenCV tutorials to capture images from a webcam [link](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#display-video) on my desktop running Ubuntu 18.04. I have a Logitec C310 webcam on `/dev/video0` and it runs fine with other webcam capture softwares like Cheese and VLC. The machine also has a Nvidia graphics card, if that would matter.

However, the capture using OpenCV (version opencv-python-3.4.4.19) always shows a white frame. I tried running it with both python2.7 and python3 (inside different virtualenv).

The same code runs fine on the laptop (different machine) with its integrated camera.

What could possibly be going on?

---

*Edit*

The image captured using `imwrite` is attached. (It might not be visible because it is white). :-/
[image: white screen grab]

Here's the screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Does it work correctly on the laptop with the C310? (comparing with different camera on different machine doesn't tell you much) If so, then what are the differences between the software installed on the two machines? Can you post an image that shows this? (e.g. use `imwrite` and attach the output)

Comment: Hi @DanMašek, using the Logitec C310 on the laptop yields the same white screen capture as observed on the desktop. Is a web camera drivers issue then? I am not using any explicit drivers or dissimilar software on both machines. Both are Ubuntu 18.04 and same libraries.

Comment: Could be a driver, but then i'd expect to see the issue in other software too. More likely something with the particular [VideoCapture backend](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/da7/videoio_overview.html) -- you could try some others. | I'd really suggest attaching both a screenshot of the window that shows the problem, as well as an image containing just the `frame` (in PNG format)

Comment: I've added the image obtained from `imwrite` and the screenshot too. I'll try out different backends and see if some option works out.

Comment: Apparently, only V4L option is supported (I tried V4L, CAP_UNICAP, CAP_DSHOW, CAP_OPENCV_MJPEG, CAP_IMAGES). For others, it cannot open device and asserts.